# How to dynamically extract the last digits in a flask website URL to set a path to it using python?

Tags: python, html, flask

Okay so I'm working on my project and I want the user to be able to visit other users profile so I'll have a link in the HTML page `<a href = "/user/5"> User X </a>` and I want them to be redirected to `@app.route("/user/"` and having user_id at the end of that path in python using flask which user_id is the 5 but that code doesn't work, is there a way to extract the number after the `/user/` so when he clicks on it from an HTML page it would send him to `@app.route("/user/5")` and save the 5 in a variable in the python code? so later I can use the 5 in my SQL code to extract the info I need, then when he goes into the site the URL would be `something.com/user/5` and the user would be able to to change the 5 to 6 in the url and it would still work taking him to a user number 6 without me having to hard-code a path to every single user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route("/user/<int:user_id>"
def users(user_id):
    print(user_id)  # its the url parameter - prints 5 in case of "/user/5"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a variable (user id) in the path, you have to define the decorator and function as below:

```
@app.route("/user/<user_id>")
def user(user_id):
    # your code here, with user_id being the string variable coming from the URL
```